# Дубликаты без ответов

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Вот такие два вопроса - [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1193032/195342), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1193147/195342). Якобы от разных пользователей. По сути - один в один. Чтобы дать ответ - надо переписывать решение олимпиадной задачи, так что просто даны советы в комментариях к более раннему вопросу.

Второй - явный кандидат на закрытие как дубликат, но ruSO возражает: у того, который указан как дубликат, нет ответа. Так что, пока нет ответа (а часто у плохого вопроса ответов просто нет), можно плодить дубликаты в любом количестве? :)

Как правильно поступать в таком случае? Не поднимать же тревогу?...

Comment: Если оба вопроса у плохого качества, то закрыть оба. Если один из них имеет полезные комментарии, то может стоить дать ответ и его оставить.

Comment: @0xdb Т.е. идти по пути "набрать 5 голосов", причем надо грешить на качество вопроса (а вопрос может быть и нормальный), потому что как дубль его закрывать нельзя...

Answer (score 4):

Не вижу ничего зазорного в том, чтобы установить на сообщении тревогу с комментарием модератору. В [чатике сайта](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/) некоторые участники (ныне даже с ромбами) на достаточно регулярной основе практикуются в предположениях о том, кто есть чей клон. Если соответствующий инструментарий подтверждает, что два участника по сути одно и то же лицо, то их учётные записи объединяются. После чего подход с закрытием дубликатом по стандартной схеме должен заработать. Помимо закрытия дубликатами есть ещё механизм объединения вопросов, доступный эксклюзивно модераторам и используемый не так часто.

Так что я бы поставил тревогу, а дальше уже надежда на адекватного модератора (других, вроде как, и быть не должно).

Comment: А что значит с ромбами?

Comment: @AimonZ. вот [эти персонажи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Answer (score -1):

Я тут недавно, поэтому могу ошибаться, но можно же указать в вопросе 2 ссылку на вопрос 1 как ответ, а не комментарий?

Либо, как писали в комментарии, скопировать полезный ответ с указанием источника. На случай, если вопрос 1 удалят.